# @types/prop-types/index has no default export

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-v4

I am trying to use https://github.com/facebook/prop-types

So I have also installed the @types/prop-types for it. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/prop-types

But I guess this error.
[ts] Module '"/node_modules/@types/prop-types/index"' has no default export.

What I am trying to accomplish is what is being done in the withRouter documentation.
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter

For example you see in their JavaScript the use of PropTypes:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'

// A simple component that shows the pathname of the current location
class ShowTheLocation extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    match: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    location: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    history: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  }

  render() {
    const { match, location, history } = this.props

    return (
      <div>You are now at {location.pathname}</div>
    )
  }
}

// Create a new component that is "connected" (to borrow redux
// terminology) to the router.
const ShowTheLocationWithRouter = withRouter(ShowTheLocation)
```

Any help on this is appreciated!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to modify your import statement like so

```
import * as PropTypes from 'prop-types'
```

What this says is create an object `PropTypes`, and import all the exports in the `prop-types` module into the `PropTypes` object.

Comment: I did same for all my `import` statements

Comment: This do solve the warning, but I don't like the way to touch the source code. Hope there is a way to fix it via babel, like how babel resolve the lodash tree-shaking issue.